# How to create product specification table in database for ecommerce site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on ecommerce project i had little confusion to create table on database.

Now i am creating multiple product in ecommerce like flikart.
for clothing i need different specification(color,size) and for mobile i need different specification(ram,storage) and each product i had different specification.

If i view the page in front end (if i selected mobile means it should display only specification based on mobile phone).

how to create table for this purpose.

Comment: This article might help, it sounds like it might be worth considering EAV: [Understanding the EAV data model and when to use it](https://inviqa.com/blog/understanding-eav-data-model-and-when-use-it)

Comment: can you create "type" field for clothes store as dress and mobile as electronics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study about `EAV` concept which is Entity Attribute value.

your tables could be:

```
categories (id, title, parent_id, status) ; here parent_id is to handle child categories
products (id, title, description, price, status, quantity)
attributes (id, title, status) ; attribute can have colors, sizes
attributevalues (id, attribute_id, value, status) ; it contains colors's attribute_id and values can be green, red, yellow etc
attributes_products (id, product_id, attribute_id, attributevalue_id, price, sign) ; it will be attaching attribute title with options to a product also how much price add or minus in case of products attributes
```

in case of query, do ask more